# How to load python module from a neighbouring package?

Tags: python, module, package, directory-structure

I've made two python packages as follows:

```
theMainFolder/
├── package_a/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── some_a_file.py
├──package_b/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── some_b_file.py
```

I now want to import some_a_file into some_b_file. I tried doing this using:

```
from package_a import some_a_file
```

but this doesn't work. Does anybody know how I can do this? All tips are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relatively add path to the location of theMainFolder and then do an import

```
import sys                                               
from os.path import dirname, abspath                     
sys.path.insert(0, dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__))))  
from package_a import some_a_file
```

Answer (score 1):

When you run the program, add the path of `theMainFolder` to the module search path:

```
PYTHONPATH=/path/to/theMainFolder python main_program.py
```

Comment: You mean changing this in for example .profile? But that wouldn't really make it portable right? Is there no other way of doing this?

Comment: @kramer65, No. I mean when you run the program.

Comment: @kramer65, `import os, import sys; sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))` at the beginning of the `some_b_file.py`.